# React Native TextInput ref causes weird crash /lockup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput, expo

i'm trying to do some `TextInput` focus stuff in React Native and need to refer to the TextInput's `ref` property... but getting some weird behaviours (Running Expo XDE) where as soon as i try to console.log the input ref, the whole thing slows down as if there's some weird memory loop. Code below.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.setInputRef = this.setInputRef.bind(this);
  }
  // function where i want to set or access the input ref
  setInputRef(input) {
    console.log('This log message is fine');
    console.log('This log message is not fine:', input); // locks up here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
            <TextInput ref={input => this.setInputRef(input)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Not sure if it's a react native issue or not. Basically i am trying to call another function passed in and called during my `setInputRef` function so that the parent component can know the ref of this textinput

Comment: Have you tried to store the ref in a variable instead of triggering a function every time the ref changes?

Comment: That works okay - but same problem if i then for example have a button that calls `focus()` on that element... and before i do the focus, try to console the variable holding the ref, it locks up.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ref to do this, you can just use this code to do what you want:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {text: ''}

  _setValue = (text) => this.setState({text})

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          autoFocus={true}
          onChangeText={this._setValue}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

In this case your `TextInput` value stores in `this.state.text`. And this component focuses the input on `componentDidMount` by using `autoFocus={true}`.

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants to do. He mentioned something about `focus` stuff and not storing or accessing input value.

Comment: I update my code and this component focuses the input on `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Yep, basically i have a Parent component that hastwo child components: one is a Comment that contains a 'reply' button, and the other is a "Type a comment" component. The reply button in Child A needs to trigger `focus()` on the input field in Child B.

Comment: FWIW i figured it out. It relates to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42017890/3842828

Comment: Basically you need to set a `ref` on the Child B component which is referenced in the Parent. Then you basically call `this.childBRef.inputFieldRef.focus(); `

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why the system 'locks up' whenever I am trying to console log the field's `ref`... However I did solve my problem which was actually *getting* the ref i needed. So not sure if this issue is 'solved' per se, but i did learn something.

Comment: This is so weird! I'm glad it wasn't just me. Also using expo.